# PHP Dropdown from Mysql, Print Results

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, selection

I have created a dropdown list and populated it with Mysql. 
I am trying to fetch the results of the users selection to show on 2 different pages
permanently but I can't get it to work.

here is my code:

```
<?php
    // Connect to the test datbase on localhost
    // That's where we created the countries table above
    mysql_connect('localhost','jakeray','pass');  mysql_select_db('wordpress');

    // Query the countries table and load all of the records
    // into an array.
    $sql = 'select * FROM manufacturers';
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    $manufacturers[] = $rec;
    ?>

    <?php
    echo '<select action="select.php" name="dropdown" class="select">';
    foreach ($manufacturers as $c)
    {       
    if ($c['id'] == $_GET['id'])
    echo "<option value=\"{$c['id']}\" selected=\"selected\">{$c['mfg']},               {$c['info']}</option>\n";
    else
    echo "<option value=\"{$c['id']}\">{$c['mfg']} {$c['info']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['select']))
    {
    $manufacturers=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dropdown']);
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT FROM manufacturers");
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    print $row['mfg'];
    }
    ?>
```

I need to display the manufacturer permanently on 2 pages. Not sure if this is right.

How do I fetch the results of the selection from the database on two different pages and make it stay 
longer after the session expires.

Comment: store the data in a db use that to repopulate the page

Comment: So when the user selects the data I need to send that data to another database to then send to the page i  want it display on?

Comment: yes, if you want to keep it, then you have to store it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_POST['select']` to `$_POST['dropdown']`. Once they choose the manufacturer, you can:

1. Store their choice in the database, possibly associated with their user's row if they're logged in
2. Store their choice in the $_SESSION, if you're using PHP sessions.